# SwiftUI : Receive Published values with conditions

Tags: swiftui, viewmodifier, property-wrapper-published

I have an `ObservableObject`  `GlobalOO` with a `@Published` value.
In any view, I can observe changes with

```
.onReceive(globalOO.$value) { newValue in
    ...
}
```

Now I only want to receive those changes according to a condition in the view

```
@State private var isActive = false

.onReceive(globalOO.$value.drop(while: { _ in isActive == false })) { newValue in
    ...
}
```

This view modifier works but seems "weird". Is there any possibility to create a view modifier that does exactly the same but is more "compact"?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var globalOO = GlobalOO()
    @State private var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .onReceive(globalOO.$value.drop(while: { _ in !isActive })) { newValue in
                // Handle newValue
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx but it is what i wrote ( == false is the same as !contidion) , I m looking to replace / change the whole drop(while: that makes code quite long and anyway seems "weird"